# CSS sticky property goes away past screen size

Tags: css

I am working on an application and have ran into some CSS styling issues. I am battling against `position: sticky` and have found myself stuck in a hole I'm not sure how to escape from.

My desired end result is to have a page that is scrollable, but I want the `<nav>` (white background), `<div id='top'>` (yellow background), and `<div class='selector'>` (pink background) to be "sticky" at the top as the user scrolls the page ([visual representation of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNRFY.jpg)).

The charts will be constant in sizing, but the list of questions will be an undetermined length. As the user scrolls through the list of questions, I want them to always have easy access to the search bar and breadcrumb heading.

**What am I doing wrong??** Right now the yellow section behaves as expected up until a certain point, then it randomly decides to scroll away and ignore the sticky. (I'm not even sure where to begin with the pink section, especially since I can't figure out the first part!)

Any help and explanations would be much appreciated to help me learn for the future.

```js
const dok = document.getElementById('dokChart').getContext('2d');
const dokChart = new Chart(dok, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [10, 20, 15, 5],
        backgroundColor: ['rgb(244, 238, 252)', 'rgb(211, 186, 243)', 'rgb(188, 151, 237)', 'rgb(155, 98, 228)'],
      },
    ],
    labels: ['DOK 1', 'DOK 2', 'DOK 3', 'DOK 4'],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false, 
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value) => {
          return ' ' + value + ' questions';
        }
      }, 
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    }
  }
});

const attempts = document.getElementById('attemptsChart').getContext('2d');
const attemptsChart = new Chart(attempts, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th+'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Attempt Progression',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(173, 173, 173)',
        data: [0.75, 1, 1.75, 2, 3],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          categorySpacing: 0
        }]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
        color: '#666',
        font: {
          weight: 'normal',
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```css
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100vw; height: 65px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5F6368;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  body {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px; left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 65px);
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 96px minmax(120px, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
      "top"
      "content"}

  /* --------[TITLE FEATURE]-------- */
  #top {
    grid-area: top;
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: 65px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px 40px;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #484848;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  #breadcrumb {
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 40px;}

  #breadcrumb ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;}
    #breadcrumb li {display: inline}

  #breadcrumb li:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: '▸';
    margin: 0px 10px;}

  #breadcrumb a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #581F98;
    font-weight: 800}

 /* --------[CHARTS]-------- */
#content {
  margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px}

#content .charts {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

.charts .DOK {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray}

.charts .attempts {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

/* ------ [TOP CONTROLS] ------ */
.selector {
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;}

.selector .title {font-weight: 800}

.selector input[type='search'] {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;}

.selector button {
    margin-top: -6px;
    font-size: 16px}


/* ------ [QUESTIONS] ------ */
#content .questions {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;}

/* Question box style */
#content .questions section {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px; /* Space under each question */
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;}
  #content .questions section:hover {border: 2px solid #D4BBF1;}

/* Question excerpt style */
.questions section .excerpt {
  padding-bottom: 24px; /* Space under excerpt */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;}

/* Main question style */
.questions section .question {
  padding-bottom: 16px; /* Space under question */
  font-weight: 800;}

/* Answer choice style */
.questions section li {
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Space under each answer option */
  list-style: none;}
  .questions section ul {margin: 0px;}

/* Spacing for checkbox in answer */
.questions section input[type='checkbox'] {margin-right: 10px;}

/* Coloring for correct answer */
.questions section li.correct {
  color: #34CB4A;
  font-weight: 800;}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='top'>
    <div class='title'> Curriculum</div>
    <div id='breadcrumb'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='?'>Main</a></li>
        <li><a href='?view=attendance'>Curriculum</a></li>
        <li><a href='?view=attendance'>Assessments</a></li>
        <li>Compare/Contrast</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='content'>
    <div class='charts'>
      <div class='DOK'><canvas id="dokChart"></canvas></div>
      <div class='attempts'><canvas id="attemptsChart"></canvas></div>
    </div>
    <div class='selector'>
      <div class='title'>16 Saved Questions:</div>
      <input type='search' placeholder='Search question bank...'>
      <button class='button purple-btn'>Create Question</button>
    </div>
    <div class='questions'>
      <section>
        <div class='excerpt'>Before you begin slicing the apples, you must first wash your hands. Cutting apples without washing your hands is not only gross, it could spread virus and germs to other people.</div>
        <div class='question'>What does the personification of the dough suggest?</div>
        <ul>
          <li class='correct'><label><input type='checkbox' checked disabled>to repair something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to replace something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to remove something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to redo something.</label></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class='excerpt'>Before you begin slicing the apples, you must first wash your hands. Cutting apples without washing your hands is not only gross, it could spread virus and germs to other people.</div>
        <div class='question'>What does the personification of the dough suggest?</div>
        <ul>
          <li class='correct'><label><input type='checkbox' checked disabled>to repair something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to replace something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to remove something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to redo something.</label></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class='excerpt'> I was a sickly, delicate boy, suffered much from asthma, and frequently had to be taken away on trips to find a place where I could breathe. One of my memories is of my father walking up and down the room with me in his arms at night when I was a very small person, and of sitting up in bed gasping, with my father and mother trying to help me. I went very little to school. I never went to the public schools, as my own children later did, both at the "Cove School" at Oyster Bay and at the "Ford School" in Washington. For a few months, I attended Professor McMullen's school in Twentieth Street near the house where I was born, but most of the time I had tutors. As I have already said, my aunt taught me when I was small.</div>
        <div class='question'>What does the personification of the dough suggest?</div>
        <ul>
          <li class='correct'><label><input type='checkbox' checked disabled>to repair something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to replace something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to remove something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to redo something.</label></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, the functionality you are looking for is done with position: sticky. For this property to function, the following is needed: Apply the position: sticky and a property top, left, right, botton, with a coarse. I leave a code of the effect for a better understanding:

```css
.styck_1{
    position: sticky;
    top: 2px;
}

.styck_2{
    position: sticky;
    top: 98px;
}


.styck_3{
    position: sticky;
    top: 193px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Position styck</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body class="container">

    <div class="bg-warning p-4 mt-3 styck_1">
        <h1>Text 1</h1>
    </div>

   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>

    <div class="bg-primary p-4 styck_2">
        <h1>Text 2</h1>
    </div>


   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>


    <div class="bg-success p-4 styck_3">
        <h1>Text 2</h1>
    </div>

   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eligendi est non ipsam ullam voluptas fugiat dignissimos illum consectetur tempora at, soluta hic beatae praesentium nostrum excepturi totam incidunt commodi. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now let's fix the problem in your html. There is a property in your html that causes conflict. Here the code and then the explanation.

```js
const dok = document.getElementById('dokChart').getContext('2d');
const dokChart = new Chart(dok, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [10, 20, 15, 5],
        backgroundColor: ['rgb(244, 238, 252)', 'rgb(211, 186, 243)', 'rgb(188, 151, 237)', 'rgb(155, 98, 228)'],
      },
    ],
    labels: ['DOK 1', 'DOK 2', 'DOK 3', 'DOK 4'],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false, 
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value) => {
          return ' ' + value + ' questions';
        }
      }, 
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    }
  }
});

const attempts = document.getElementById('attemptsChart').getContext('2d');
const attemptsChart = new Chart(attempts, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th+'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Attempt Progression',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(173, 173, 173)',
        data: [0.75, 1, 1.75, 2, 3],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          categorySpacing: 0
        }]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
        color: '#666',
        font: {
          weight: 'normal',
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100vw; height: 65px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5F6368;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  body {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px; left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: calc(100vh - 65px);*/
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 96px minmax(120px, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
      "top"
      "content"}

  /* --------[TITLE FEATURE]-------- */
  #top {
    grid-area: top;
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: 65px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px 40px;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #484848;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  #breadcrumb {
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 40px;}

  #breadcrumb ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;}
    #breadcrumb li {display: inline}

  #breadcrumb li:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: '▸';
    margin: 0px 10px;}

  #breadcrumb a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #581F98;
    font-weight: 800}

 /* --------[CHARTS]-------- */
#content {
  margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px}

#content .charts {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

.charts .DOK {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray}

.charts .attempts {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

/* ------ [TOP CONTROLS] ------ */
.selector {
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 161px;}

.selector .title {font-weight: 800}

.selector input[type='search'] {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;}

.selector button {
    margin-top: -6px;
    font-size: 16px}


/* ------ [QUESTIONS] ------ */
#content .questions {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;}

/* Question box style */
#content .questions section {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px; /* Space under each question */
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;}
  #content .questions section:hover {border: 2px solid #D4BBF1;}

/* Question excerpt style */
.questions section .excerpt {
  padding-bottom: 24px; /* Space under excerpt */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;}

/* Main question style */
.questions section .question {
  padding-bottom: 16px; /* Space under question */
  font-weight: 800;}

/* Answer choice style */
.questions section li {
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Space under each answer option */
  list-style: none;}
  .questions section ul {margin: 0px;}

/* Spacing for checkbox in answer */
.questions section input[type='checkbox'] {margin-right: 10px;}

/* Coloring for correct answer */
.questions section li.correct {
  color: #34CB4A;
  font-weight: 800;}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='top'>
    <div class='title'> Curriculum</div>
    <div id='breadcrumb'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='?'>Main</a></li>
        <li><a href='?view=attendance'>Curriculum</a></li>
        <li><a href='?view=attendance'>Assessments</a></li>
        <li>Compare/Contrast</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='content'>
    <div class='charts'>
      <div class='DOK'><canvas id="dokChart"></canvas></div>
      <div class='attempts'><canvas id="attemptsChart"></canvas></div>
    </div>
    <div class='selector'>
      <div class='title'>16 Saved Questions:</div>
      <input type='search' placeholder='Search question bank...'>
      <button class='button purple-btn'>Create Question</button>
    </div>
    <div class='questions'>
      <section>
        <div class='excerpt'>Before you begin slicing the apples, you must first wash your hands. Cutting apples without washing your hands is not only gross, it could spread virus and germs to other people.</div>
        <div class='question'>What does the personification of the dough suggest?</div>
        <ul>
          <li class='correct'><label><input type='checkbox' checked disabled>to repair something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to replace something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to remove something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to redo something.</label></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class='excerpt'>Before you begin slicing the apples, you must first wash your hands. Cutting apples without washing your hands is not only gross, it could spread virus and germs to other people.</div>
        <div class='question'>What does the personification of the dough suggest?</div>
        <ul>
          <li class='correct'><label><input type='checkbox' checked disabled>to repair something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to replace something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to remove something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to redo something.</label></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class='excerpt'> I was a sickly, delicate boy, suffered much from asthma, and frequently had to be taken away on trips to find a place where I could breathe. One of my memories is of my father walking up and down the room with me in his arms at night when I was a very small person, and of sitting up in bed gasping, with my father and mother trying to help me. I went very little to school. I never went to the public schools, as my own children later did, both at the "Cove School" at Oyster Bay and at the "Ford School" in Washington. For a few months, I attended Professor McMullen's school in Twentieth Street near the house where I was born, but most of the time I had tutors. As I have already said, my aunt taught me when I was small.</div>
        <div class='question'>What does the personification of the dough suggest?</div>
        <ul>
          <li class='correct'><label><input type='checkbox' checked disabled>to repair something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to replace something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to remove something.</label></li>
          <li><label><input type='checkbox' disabled>to redo something.</label></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Run the code in full screen**

Height property `height: calc(100vh - 65px);` in body css was affecting how position sticky works

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have tried this, but something is not working right. Here is a snip from the above, I have both position sticky and a top specified but if you scroll too far, the sticky stops working. ```#top {position: sticky; top: 65px;}```

Comment: I'm trying to apply it to your code, when I have it I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Mathew Check the update of my answer and comment if now it will be easier for you to continue

Comment: @Mathew No problem